# Kibana4 in IIS without reverse proxy

Tags: iis, kibana-4

I could successfully get Kibana 3 hosted on IIS by adding a couple of MIME types (".json" and ".").

However, the same trick doesn't seem to be working in Kibana 4, I haven't dug deep yet as to why or what has changed, has anybody achieved this?

P.S. I don't want to do a reverse proxy as some people have suggested, this is because the server in which it resides already has a reverse proxy for something else and its rules will conflict with that of kibana 4 and I don't want to put up another server just for this.

Comment: anyone has an answer for this?